# How to add linear gradient to a rounded container in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How to add linear gradient to a rounded container in flutter. Here is my code. This does apply a gradient, but it appears like a rectangle container on the top of the rounded container.

```
Container(
height:300,
 width: double.infinity,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 0, left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  image: AssetImage("assets/images/img.png"),
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                color: Colors.black),
child:Container(
decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [
                    Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                    Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
                  ],
                ),
child:MoreWidgets(),
),
),
```

Comment: try `clipBehavior` in outer `Container` - but honestly why dont you use `gradient` in that outer `Container` - why do you need that inner `Container`?

Comment: It didnt work when i add gradient in the outer container

Comment: gradient is added below the image

Comment: ok, i missed that `DecorationImage`... - still `clipBehavior` should work in outer `Container`

Comment: How do i implemet, i tried googlng but could understad, could you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to gradient covers all of image you should remove padding from container and then add `borderRadius` to second Container like code below:

```
Container(
        height: 300,
        width: double.infinity,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 0, left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              image: AssetImage("assets/images/img.png"),
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
            color: Colors.black),
        child: Container(
          child: MoreWidgets(),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```